# Error in changing background color of row in JFace tableviewer

Tags: java, jface, e4, tableviewer

I want to change the row color of the tableviewer depends on certain conditions. I have used the following code snippet.

```
tableViewer.setLabelProvider(new ColumnLabelProvider(){
        @Override
        public Color getForeground(Object element){
             super.clearListeners();
             if((((MyClass)element).getMyMethodValue()).equals("ABC"))
               return Display.getDefault().getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_GRAY);
             else
               return null;
        }
    });
```

The color of the row is changing but the text each cell is changed to the object name of model class "MYClass" like com.sample.JfaceProject.model.MyClass@394083 . I am cofused why the text is changed in every cell of the table. Am I doing it correctly? Can anyone suggest me some ideas.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a `ColumnLabelProvider` you must use it for everything to do with the column - so you need to override `getText` as well as `getForeground`.

The default `getText` for `ColumnLabelProvider` is

```
public String getText(Object element) {
  return element == null ? "" : element.toString();//$NON-NLS-1$
}
```

It is the `element.toString()` which is producing the 'com.sample.JfaceProject.model.MyClass@394083' output - this is the default `Object.toString()` output.

Comment: In my tableviewer one column is of string type , others are checkd/unchecked Images. Should I have to do override getText() and getImage() method for all the columns? Is there any other way?

Comment: Once you start to use ColumnLabelProvider you have to use it for all columns.

Comment: Is it correct to implement ITableColorProvider and ITableLabelProvider to set the color for rows?

Comment: Yes, you can use those with an ITableLabelProvider. There are several different ways of doing things!

Comment: Now it is working fine. The color of the row is greyed out . But I couldnt edit the checkbox. Do I have to call EditingSupport again after change of color in rows?

Comment: No the color should not affect the editing support. But if you are using ColumnLabelProvider you probably have to set the editing support on the TableViewerColumn

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54046/discussion-between-acjb-and-greg-449).